# BIRT reporting exception on postgreSQL DB

Tags: postgresql, tomcat, report, birt

I designed the report design file (test_report.rptdesign ) on BIRT report designer. I can see the report by clicking " View report in web viewer" on BIRT report designer. But, when I try to see the report with TOMCAT , there is "There is no report design object available " error.
The TOMCAT and "BIRT VIEWER" is configured correctly. I put the "BIRT VIEWER filse under "C:\xampp\tomcat\webapps" folder. And I have correctly configured  the "\birt-viewer\WEB-INF\web.xml" file . I tried the sample reports (customers.rptdesign,TopNPercent.rptdesign) on TOMCAT server, it works correctly. 
But,when I tried with postgreSQL , it didn't work, there is exception. I put the  "test_report.rptdesign " file under "C:\xampp\tomcat\webapps\brt-example\report" folder. could you give me some suggesstion,please ?

the error message is as follows:

```
There is no report design object available.

org.eclipse.birt.report.exception.ViewerException: There is no report design object available.
at org.eclipse.birt.report.context.ViewerAttributeBean.__init(ViewerAttributeBean.java:230)
at org.eclipse.birt.report.context.BaseAttributeBean.init(BaseAttributeBean.java:233)
at org.eclipse.birt.report.context.ViewerAttributeBean.(ViewerAttributeBean.java:113)
at org.eclipse.birt.report.context.BirtContext.__init(BirtContext.java:44)
at org.eclipse.birt.report.context.BaseContext.(BaseContext.java:69)
at org.eclipse.birt.report.context.BirtContext.(BirtContext.java:30)
at org.eclipse.birt.report.servlet.ViewerServlet.__getContext(ViewerServlet.java:150)
at org.eclipse.birt.report.servlet.BirtSoapMessageDispatcherServlet.doPost(BirtSoapMessageDispatcherServlet.java:204)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:646)
at org.apache.axis.transport.http.AxisServletBase.service(AxisServletBase.java:327)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:727)
at org.eclipse.birt.report.servlet.BirtSoapMessageDispatcherServlet.service(BirtSoapMessageDispatcherServlet.java:112)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:303)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
at org.eclipse.birt.report.filter.ViewerFilter.doFilter(ViewerFilter.java:68)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:220)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:122)
at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:503)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:170)
at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:103)
at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:950)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:116)
at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:421)
at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1070)
at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:611)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:316)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally solved this problem by editing the following line in Eclipse "XML Source" tab:

```
<report xmlns="http://www.eclipse.org/birt/2005/design" version="3.2.23" id="1">
```

All I had to do was to change version from 3.2.23 to 3.2.10. You can do that by editing the *.rptdesign file directly in notepad.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, it was cause by the SFTP transfer I was doing: binary (default with filezilla as I guess it interpret the .rptdesign as a binary) instead of ASCII